# How to identify too many left join for a single left join based sql command

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to write a one single query instead of running too many command to fetch a question list.

There are 2 kind of user : Guest and registered. Both are maintained in 2 kind of databases.

I am writing this queries so please someone explain me how I can differentiate them.

```
SELECT * FROM question
LEFT JOIN `user` ON user.`ID` = question.`lastAnswererID`
LEFT JOIN guestusera ON guestusera.aID = question.lastAnswererID
```

Remember that user table may contain properties of user where guest only name ID and Email address.

Now I want to calculate the reputation but didn't know how to add them in this one too.

```
SELECT SUM(reputation) FROM action WHERE userid=?id AND reputation>0
```

Following ?id is the guestusera.aId and user.Id in all 2 case respectively (registered and unregistered).

Now this is about the lastanswerId information. There is another thing I want to fetch from user and guestuserq is question.askerId.

now I can get the other information. how I can differentiate them. the differentiate means I want to know if user is guest or registered. If user.lastanswererId is null then it means user is unregistered.

Someone guide me how to mix all these commands.

```
 if (rdr["lastAnswererID"] == DBNull.Value)
 {
    UserManager.UserSummary user = new UserManager.UserSummary();
    user.Email = rdr["email"].ToString();
    user.Name = rdr["name"].ToString();
    user.URL = rdr["website"].ToString();
    ques.LastAnswerer = user;
 }
 else
 {
    UserManager.UserSummary userSumm = new UserManager.UserSummary();
    userSumm.ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
    userSumm.Name = rdr["name"].ToString();
    userSumm.HasPhoto = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["hasPhoto"]);
    ques.LastAnswerer = userSumm;
 }
```

This is how my C# code handle this. Do someone know now how can I access other user from user table who ask the questions. There are too many user is attached to the question.

Comment: What did you mean here "Remember that user table contain may properties of user when guest only name ID and Email address."

Comment: Could you please provide a simple ER diagram or database diagram of your tables and could you please specify which records in your tables you want to fetch?

Comment: @Mecek their is 2 kind of user referenced to my question table. one is guest and second is registered.

Answer (score 0):

This problem's solution can be done in 2 way.

1. use CASE WHEN END in MySQL.
2. MySQL inner join.

inner join is better so you can use it if this problem is happen to you.